# Why is pickle salty? How does salt get into pickle?

Tags: osmosis

I know this may look like some question easily answered with common sense, but please read.

If water is the solvent wouldn't the only thing that moves be water? (Osmosis)

**Edit:** this is basically what I think. If you imagine the skin of whatever you are pickling as a membrane that prohibit the flow of electrolytes but allows that if water. Then salt, NaCl, cannot move anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concept of a cell is a little vague. Although the cell wall is made from a diglyceride bilayer, it is not impregnable. In fact, there are many proteins that pass through the cell wall where dissolved material can pass. One of the proteins is called the [sodium potassium pump](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-imDC1txWw). In a living cell, the protein uses ATP to move sodium out of the cell and drag potassium into the cell. Both of these ions are against the gradient. In a non-living cell, such as the pickle, sodium ions can move across the cell membrane and make the cells salty.

Comment: So even after being cut off, the cucumber, say for ex, will not absorb any sodium unless it's cell is completely dead?

Comment: Also, does Cl also come in like this and get recombined with sodium?

Comment: Sodium leaks in even if the cell is alive. There is nothing preventing chloride ions from passing through the cell membrane.